# WIX Installer Error: The system cannot open the device or specified file

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WIX installer that acts as a content installer for users. It's supposed to install these files in a specific directory. Unfortunately when I run it I get the following error: "The system cannot open the device or specified file." This then gives me error code 2755 after canceling the install (retry does not work).

I've looked through other questions with similar issues, and it does not appear to be an encryption problem on temp, the install folder, or the MSI installer itself - these all appear fine. This also isn't a problem with the C:\Windows\Installer folder being read-only.

I've never had a problem with a WIX installer before. What other things can I try to get this working?

Comment: Install your MSI with a command such as msiexec /I [path to msi] /l*vx [path to text log file] to get more detail about the error and the timing (because you don't say if it happens as soon as the MSI starts or during the progress sequence). 2755 is a downstream error - it's the first one that matters. Are you using drive letters or subst drives anywhere?

Comment: It looks like access rights issue

Comment: I think you can get this error when there are many files and the setup exceeds the maximum size of a CAB file used in the MSI. Could this be the case?

Comment: @PhilDW, I believe this is the case. This was meant to be a ~4.5gb install, and looking it up the max cab file size is 2gb. I might have to do this in two separate patches. Thanks for pointing me in this direction, I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem solved when the installer run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing all of the following errors when installing my 3.5 GB .msi generated by WiX:

- DEBUG: Error 2709:  The specified Component name ('cmpF7216C180B7A7119CC61FDB3BD209D5D') not found in Component Table.
- DEBUG: Error 2755:  Server returned unexpected error 110 attempting to install package D:\...\setup.msi.
- The system cannot open the device or specified file

Turning off EmbedCab made them all go away:

```
<Wix>...
  <Product>...
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="no" />
```

I unfortunately now have 30 cab files to deal with, but at least the install succeeds.